# How to open all .txt and .log files in the current directory, search, and print the file the search was found

Tags: python, search, file-io

I'm trying to search for a string in all text and log files in the current directory. And if it finds a match, print the text or log file where the match was found. Is this possible, and how can I manipulate the code below to accomplish this task?

```
  fiLe = open(logfile, "r")
  userString = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
  for line in fiLe.readlines():
      if userString in line:
         print line
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import os
directory = os.path.join("c:\\","path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
           for line in f:
              if userstring in line:
                 print "file: " + os.path.join(root,file)             
                 break
           f.close()
```

Comment: In windows would the walk method be like os.walk('c:/Python27') or something along those lines? Thanks!

Comment: Note that `str.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])` can take a tuple for suffix. Could get cumbersome with too many "or" comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

He asked for a flat readdir, not for a recursive file tree walk.
os.listdir() does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Do you *have* to do it in Python? Otherwise, simply `grep -l "string" *.txt *.log` would work.

Comment: lbrahim yeah, I need to to do this in Python. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Andre Caron It looks like a legitimate question ... you must be bright when you can hear text! ... and who are you to determine what it sounds like? Lad, I finished school long ago ... this is a self-interest hobby. Nothing better to do with your time then to bring negativity. People like you ....